# $(this).next() return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery in order to display or not a div but I couldn't select it with my jQuery code. It returns me `undefined`. Can someone help me please?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.questions', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<p id="selected">' + this.innerHTML + '</p>'));
  $(this).parent().next().css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions_impt">
  <p id="testde" class="questions">Comment vous rejoindre ?</p>
  <div class="quest_join">
    <p>Pour nous rejoindre il faut que tu t'inscrives a l'association. Remplis le formulaire ci-joint et renvois le nous a l'adresse XXX. Tu recevras ensuite un mail t'annonçant ton arrivé l'association. Tu peux aussi venir a nos journées d'initiation tout
      le long de l'année si tu veux d'abord découvrir le longboard avant de t'engager !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You appear to be selecting the next sibling of `.questions_impt`, which you've not shown. Is that the intended behaviour? Seeing a more complete sample of the HTML would help a lot here.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, could you give more details?

Comment: if you're trying to select the the "quest_join" div, then you just want `$(this).next()` (without the .parent()) because the div is next to (i.e. a sibling of) the "questions" div, not of its parent.

Comment: Yes this should "$(this).parent()" means you seeking next sibling of "#questions_impt" element, we can see which is not available in your DOM tree, so what else you expect?

Comment: From my reading of the question, you replace the `this`/`$(this)` node with another element, therefore - and unfortunately I can't test this currently - I'd expect that `this` no longer has a `parent()`, since it's no longer in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are trying to access the next element of the parent 
you can acccess the element by id

```
 $(document).on('click', '.questions', function() {
   $(this).replaceWith($('<p id="selected">' + this.innerHTML + '</p>'));  
   $("#selected").next().css("border", "1px solid red");
 });
```

Comment: if you're going to make a snippet, please at least make it runnable - otherwise just post plain code. People will expect the "run code snippet" button to provide them with a usable demonstration instead of an error message. You need to include jQuery, and add some HTML so that the code actually does something visible. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this advice i'm new contributor so i don't know that

Comment: No problem. Always good to learn something new. By the way, with JavaScript/HTML questions, a runnable snippet generally would attract more upvotes, as people can easily be certain your solution will actually work. So it's good to provide one if you can make it run...usually that's not too difficult to achieve. Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$(this).parent().next()` on `.questions` click event.

Problem :

- `$(this)` = The DIV with `.questions` class
- Its parent `parent()` = `<div id="questions_impt">`
- Its `next()`, you have not posted any code after ending  `<div id="questions_impt">` tag.

Major Problem :

- You are using `replaceWith()` and directly to `$(this)` inside own click event
- It will removing `.questions` from the DOM, So it will not work after that.

> Solution :
>
> - Change the sequence of lines, as below
> - First line : `$(this).parent().next().css("border", "1px solid red");`
> - Second line : `$(this).replaceWith($('<p id="selected">' + this.innerHTML + '</p>'));`

Check below code :

```js
$(document).on('click','.questions',function(){
   $(this).parent().next().css("border","1px solid red");
   $(this).replaceWith($('<p id="selected">' + this.innerHTML + '</p>'));
});
```

```css
.questions{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions_impt">
    <p id="testde" class="questions">Comment vous rejoindre ?</p>
    <div class="quest_join">
        <p>Pour nous rejoindre il faut que tu t'inscrives a l'association.
            Remplis le formulaire ci-joint et renvois le nous a l'adresse XXX. Tu recevras ensuite un mail t'annonçant ton arrivé
            l'association. Tu peux aussi venir a nos journées d'initiation tout le long de l'année si tu veux d'abord découvrir le
            longboard avant de t'engager !</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
 i'm here.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answer and explications it works perfect for me !

Answer (score 1):

-From your code what I understood is that when you click on the element with class "questions". You want to display a div with a red border.

- If you just want to do this interaction only once then just remove a parent, see code below

```js
$(document).on('click', '.questions', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<p id="selected">' + this.innerHTML + '</p>'));
  $(this).next().css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

- This code will work but again why are you trying to replace an element with question class. If you want to show that it is selected then just add class to that element.
- Well if you want to do this interaction only once then it's fine but make sure that you don't add another element and gave the same id "selected".

Let me know if need any clarification.

cheers